# How does the f-string in this Python function work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string, pep

Hi I found the below function on some website somewhere and just have a couple of questions. The function returns a diamond of n lines made from asterisks.

1. Is that a concatenated for loop? Is that a thing you can do?
2. What is going on in that f-string? How does `'':*<{line*2+1}` work?

```
def diamond(n):
    result = ""
    for line in list(range(n)) + list(reversed(range(n-1))):
        result += f"{'': <{n - line - 1}} {'':*<{line*2+1}}\n"

    return result
```

Comment: It's in the documentation. I don't want to copy-paste it into an answer so here's the link: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings

Comment: What part of the loop are you referring to when you say "concatenated loop"?

Comment: the fstring is basically equivalent with `' ' * (n - line - 1) + '*' * (line*2+1) + "\n"`

Comment: also check [this docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) out to understand more

Comment: @Arcanefoam `for line in list(range(n)) + list(reversed(range(n-1))):` 
The part with the addition operator. What is the effect of using it this way? Would it be fair to say its syntax sugar for two for loops?

Comment: @MaxPhillips as @bereal mentioned in his reply, the two lists will be concatenated, i.e. in python adding lists concatenate them; any expression between the `in` and the colon `:` will be evaluated before entering the loop, so you dont have two loops, just a single loop over the concatenated lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the iteration: yes, it iterates over a concatenation of two ranges, but it's not the most optimal way to do it. Using [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) looks like a better choice.

For the formatting part: `f"{'':*<{n}}"` literally means "right-pad the empty string with `*` to the length of `n` characters". In other words, it's some cryptic way of saying `'*' * n`.

More generally, everything that goes after `:` defines the format in the [format specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Overall, this is quite a bad piece of code, don't use it as an example.

Comment: Ah thanks that makes more sense! Could you give an different example of what the `:` and `<` operators are doing here though? Is the colon just a way of appending to a string?

Comment: @MaxPhillips the format language is described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), but there's also a great site [PyFormat](https://pyformat.info/) that gives plenty of examples.

Comment: You're right that is a great website! Gonna take a closer look.